# Edits to Clarify Questions for Posterity

Tags: discussion

One of the common things I see arise is for an author of a question to ask a question about one thing but was actually meaning another. Here's a very fresh example:

[Polymorphism and Slicing with references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894741/polymorphism-and-slicing-with-references?noredirect=1#comment55553087_33894741)

The question is about object slicing but the example shown exhibits no slicing. It's really exhibiting the need for double dispatch or some other form of branching based on the type of an object.

It's a decent, clear question though with an MCVE. All the author did was mistakenly diagnose the problem which is not uncommon at that level.

Yet it seems really intrusive if we edit the question and title for the author, but the author probably won't do it (it would change the very nature of his question). To do it for him could also trample all over his intentions.

So I'm wondering what to do about these -- simply keep them as they are, a misleading question leading to a clear answer, or update the question (still in sync with the answer).

It's awkward to say the least, and the kind of edit that, unless people took the time to really examine what the author was asking, could seem very intrusive and unwarranted. It might also upset the author. Ugh.

I tend to just leave them as is to avoid toe-stepping. But there are far too many decent answers to misleading questions that I see like this, where they'll likely end up being overlooked due to the misunderstanding of the person raising the question.

Comment: Just edit it.  You have full editing privileges, so it's not like you have to worry about confusing reviewers.  If the OP doesn't like the change, they can roll it back revise it on their own.  If you want, make it more apparent they can comment ping you by leaving a comment about your edit.

Comment: I see -- maybe it's decent enough if we edit it and then leave a polite comment on why we did it.

Comment: I thought it might be interesting since I don't see it being done more often -- the author asks about X but actually meant Y, the answer addresses Y, but the question still remains about X. :-D

Comment: Yeah, if all the answers correctly identify the question as Y, there's no reason to not edit the question to match.  Of course if there are a few who still see X, then you'll have to be more cautious...

Comment: @ryanyuyu all editors are pingable, no need to leave a comment

Comment: @Braiam yes, but it's _more apparent_ to users if you also leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just edit the post title to be more succinct. The question asker mistakenly diagnosed the problem as you correctly mention here - that should not be a reason to leave the question in the same state. The question is not just for the benefit of the particular user - it is supposed to be an addition to a huge repository of useful questions and answers. And if it's left in its current state, that is, "misleading", it won't be of much use to future visitors.

So I think editing the question and leaving a clear-enough reason as to why is the best course of action. Of course, if the user doesn't like the change, they can always revert it back. Additionally, you can leave a comment under the question as to why you made the edit to help clarify things a bit, but that's optional.