# Should I change my misunderstood question to fit a well made answer?

Tags: discussion

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963033/how-to-propagate-callback-promise-value-on-model-find-obj-callback) question, titled ***How to Propagate Callback Promise Value on Model.find( obj, callback)?***, but the answers for this question have not only fulfilled my final objective but have also changed my understanding of the subject.

So, the best answer do not address a *propagation of a promise value* but, instead, change the subject to a promise-like error and success callbacks.

If anyone sees the question title and look to the answer, it will not fit. Should we change title or some important information regarding the initial understanding of the question by the question owner?

Answer (score 8):

Close or edit question.

There are generally several cases for such questions:

- question was asked in such a way that almost everyone understood it in one particular way which was not at all OP's intention/question (i.e. it could be because of using wrong terms). In such case I'd recommend asking new question and editing original by adding "if you are looking for Xxxx check out other question" at the end and possibly edit title if it clearly wrong/too general.
- question asked to do particular action (like add DateTime field to SQL) but sample/approach was completely off (i.e. use some strange string formatting to construct SQL statement). In such case edit question with clear goal and keep  misguided attempt to solve the problem as it likely lead users trying similar approach to correct question.
- question asked about one thing but totally changed in comments and such modified version answered with good post. Definitely need to edit question to inline comments and align with answer.

I think your question is of second kind (and code you provided is quite plausible approach). I'd recommend replacing first paragraph with actual goal and possibly adjust title.

Comment: I agree with the above, but would like to emphasize: in this particular case, the question is not being changed **to fit the answer**. Rather, it is being _elaborated_ to make it more clear. One should _not_ change the fundamental nature of the question after it's been correctly answered, for the reason given above: other users may be following the same misguided path, and they will need the original, misguided question in order to find the answer they need. I.e. make sure someone with the same flawed understanding of a topic can find the question in a search and gain as much from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to face this dilemma more from the outside and have a couple of questions on here about this very problem of trying to edit questions which were asking about one thing but got mostly answers about another.

[Edits to Clarify Questions for Posterity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311019/edits-to-clarify-questions-for-posterity)

It is not uncommon when we're tackling a new subject to ask about one thing and actually realize the greatest answer requires us to change the way we were even looking at the problem. I've been coding for many years and I still get tunnel vision where I stubbornly want to find an immediate solution for an immediate problem where I really needed to rethink my whole strategy. Sometimes it takes someone else to point that out unless I totally slam hard into a brick wall.

My suggestion is kind of look around you, make sure no one is adding an answer to your former question, and sneak in an edit... and maybe edit it in a way so the original question is still there, but at the bottom so that people looking at the comments and discussion that lead to the revised question aren't so confused.

You might be able to gently "deprecate" your old answer that way, wipe it out. Keeping it in there as deprecated temporarily might be a safe transition for a short period so that, in the event that someone does end up answering your original Q more directly, you don't screw them over.